# I'm getting: Subquery returned more than 1 value, but I don't have a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE P
SET NRI_1 = (WI_1 * .8)
FROM AC_Property P 
WHERE COALESCE(WI_1,0) <> 0 and RSV_CAT = 'PDNP'
```

Comment: Why you are using `FROM`?

Comment: Is there an after update trigger on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
UPDATE AC_Property
SET NRI_1 = (WI_1 * .8)
WHERE COALESCE(WI_1,0) <> 0 and RSV_CAT = 'PDNP'
```

You don't need to `FROM` because you are using the same table.

Also if you have a `Trigger` it will cause the error, because you update more than one (1) row.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use ?

```
UPDATE AC_Property
SET NRI_1 = (WI_1 * .8)
WHERE COALESCE(WI_1,0) <> 0 and RSV_CAT = 'PDNP'
```

Comment: I get the same error when I remove the FROM and put the table name in the Update.

Comment: I went back and found a trigger.  When I disabled the trigger it worked.  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Do not jjust disable the trigger, fix it so it will work again